# Unable to install the X-Pack plugin for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I have installed both Elasticsearch and Kibana on the same server and I am trying to install the X-Pack plugin for the Elasticsearch. I have downloaded the plugin zip file and I tried the following command.

```
./plugin install file:///root/x-pack-5.1.1.zip
```

And I got the following error:

> Verifying file:/root/x-pack-5.1.1.zip checksums if available ...
>   NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
>   ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip
>   `

Comment: Please can you precise which version of elastic search you use

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with elastic search-plugin command ?

Comment: Yes I tried it.. Apparently x-pac should be the same version as the Elastic Search and Kibana. Thanks anyways.. I will try installing from the scratch again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps, for me its working.

```
To add xpack extension for elasticsearch
go to /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack

To add xpack extension for kibana
go to /usr/share/kibana/bin
bin/kibana-plugin install x-pack

Set the passwords for all built-in users:
go to /usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/x-pack/setup-passwords interactive

Here it will ask passwords for installed services

Open the kibana.yml file and change the following:
    elasticsearch.username: "ur-username"
    elasticsearch.password: "ur-password"

Restart elasticsearch, logstash and kibana
```